# Mapping Map<String, List<>> with List<>

Tags: java, list, mapping

I need some help mapping a `Map<String, List<Fee>>` with a `List<FeeRequest>`.

`Fee` object looks like this:

```
private String feeCode;
```

`FeeRequest` objects looks like this:

```
private String feeCode;
private String debtorAccount;
```

So what I need is to map:

*String debtorAccount(from map)* **->** *debtorAccount(from List)*

*feeCode(from List from map)* **->** *feeCode(from List)*

I want to try **not** to use `foreach`, but instead learn to properly use `.stream().map()` features.

What I've managed to do:

`Map<String, List<Fee>> feeAccounts` is parsed from another method.

```
 List<FeeRequest> feeRequests = feeAccounts.entrySet().stream().map(feeAcc -> {
        FeeRequest request = new FeeRequest();
        request.setDebtorAccount(feeAcc.getKey());
        request.setFeeCode(...);
        return request;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think that my approach is bad, but I don't know how to make it work. I tried looking at some examples but they're too basic. So I would be glad to get any help. Thanks!

Comment: `I think that my approach is bad` - why?

Comment: @Eran because I can't map the feeCode, it doesn't show me the Fee objects fields

Comment: you can access the `List<Fee>` with `feeAcc.getValue()`. It's not clear what you wish to do with it, though.

Comment: @Eran Basically what I want is to `FeeRequest.setFeeCode(Fee.getFeeCode())`. Feecodes from one list map with feecodes from another

Comment: But each entry of the input Map contains a `List` of `Fee` instances. Which one of them do you wish to use? Or do you want to create multiple `FeeRequest` instances (one for each `Fee` instance)?

Comment: @Eran Let me rethink my question, thanks for the effort tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each `Fee` instance should generate a `FeeRequest` instance, you need `flatMap`:

```
List<FeeRequest> feeRequests =
    feeAccounts.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .flatMap(feeAcc -> feeAcc.getValue()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(f -> {
                                            FeeRequest request = new FeeRequest();
                                            request.setDebtorAccount(feeAcc.getKey());
                                            request.setFeeCode(f.getCode());
                                            return request;
                                        }))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes because you get a lot of lists in the first step which then have to be merged into one map.

Answer (score 0):

If `FeeRequest` has a constructor with two arguments you can use something like this:

```
feeAccounts.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(
                accountEntry -> accountEntry.getValue().stream().map(
                        fee -> new FeeRequest(
                                accountEntry.getKey(),
                                fee.getFeeCode()
                        )
                )
        ).collect(toList());
```